# grep result is not what I want

Tags: grep, pipe

`java -version` output like this:

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

then I run `grep` command, but can't get my expected result.

```
>java -version | grep "version"
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

My expected result is just only the first line

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
```

why ?

Comment: Because error stream does not go through `grep`. The `|` pipe redirects a standard output stream only.

Answer (score 1):

`java -version` prints text to standard err, instead of standard output. so you should do:

```
java -version 2>&1|grep "version"
```